# Babun - Open zsh on current directory for Intellij products

Tags: shell, zsh

I have Babun installed and Zsh configured, I've been using it for months and I've configured my WebStorm to execute `intellij.bat` as a shell program.

**intellij.bat**

```
@echo off
set currentdir=%cd:\=/%
@echo cd %currentdir% > "%USERPROFILE%\.babun\cygwin\home\%USERNAME%\.bashrc_cd"
call %USERPROFILE%\.babun\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i -ls
```

The thing is: This relies on **bash** and I want to use **.babun\cygwin\bin\zsh.exe** instead.

But I don't know how to configure it so it opens in the right directory.

*I don't know whether I should open this question in SuperUser or AskUbuntu ^_^*

PS: Could someone create the tag `babun`? https://babun.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your zshrc to start in the proper directory.

- Add `cd $OLDPWD` on a newline in
  `%USERPROFILE%\.babun\cygwin\etc\zshrc`
- In your IDEA IDE set Settings > Tools > Terminal > Shell path :
  `<your babun install dir>\.babun\cygwin\bin\zsh.exe`

With IntelliJ I sometimes need to highlight a different window before the  shell will load. In PyCharm it works without problems